# Foreach loop is giving wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, foreach

I have table data with two conditions `price_id =2` and `price_id = 1` and data as like below .
[image]

So here my condition if `weekday_am` column value is `null` or `empty` or `0.00` at `price_id =2` i need to take that value at `price_id = 1` and the same logic will apply for the columns `weekday_pm` , `weekend_am`, `weekend_pm` . So what i m doing is i have written two queries with two different conditions and checking the values using foreach loop . But its giving wrong results .

Query code :

```
$ArrayTier = BundlePrice::where('bundle_id',$id)->where('price_id','=','2')->get();
             $ArrayDefault = BundlePrice::where('bundle_id',$id)->where('price_id','=','1')->get();
             foreach($ArrayTier as $value)
             {  
                $bundle_id = $value->bundle_id;
                $asset_id = $value->asset_id;

                   foreach($ArrayDefault as $v)
                    {

                        if(!empty($value->weekday_am) || ($value->weekday_am != null))
                        {
                            $weekam =  $value->weekday_am;
                        }else{
                            $weekam = $v->weekday_am;
                        }

                        if(!empty($value->weekday_pm) || ($value->weekday_pm != null))
                        {
                            $weekpm =  $value->weekday_pm;
                        }else{
                            $weekpm = $v->weekday_pm;
                        }

                        if(!empty($value->weekend_am) || ($value->weekend_am != null))
                        {
                            $nonweekam =  $value->weekend_am;
                        }else{
                            $nonweekam = $v->weekend_am;
                        }

                       if(!empty($value->weekend_pm) || ($value->weekend_pm != null))
                        {
                            $nonweekpm =  $value->weekend_pm;
                        }else{
                            $nonweekpm = $v->weekend_pm;
                        }



                    }
                $primaryArray[] = ['asset_id' => $asset_id,'weekam' => $weekam,'weekpm' => $weekpm,'nonweekam' => $nonweekam,'nonweekpm' => $nonweekpm];
             }
```

For the above query i'm getting wrong like the values are not changing its taking only the last row values at `price_id =1`

The result the above code is :

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 2
    "weekam" => 150.0
    "weekpm" => 320.0
    "nonweekam" => 160.0
    "nonweekpm" => 420.0
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 1
    "weekam" => 120.0
    "weekpm" => 180.0
    "nonweekam" => 220.0
    "nonweekpm" => 420.0
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 4
    "weekam" => 120.0
    "weekpm" => 320.0
    "nonweekam" => 220.0
    "nonweekpm" => 420.0
  ]
]
```

If you see the above , same values are repeating for few places . 
But expecting results should be like below :

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 2
    "weekam" => 150.0
    "weekpm" => 300.0
    "nonweekam" => 160.0
    "nonweekpm" => 400.0
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 1
    "weekam" => 110.0
    "weekpm" => 180.0
    "nonweekam" => 210.0
    "nonweekpm" => 410.0
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "asset_id" => 4
    "weekam" => 120.0
    "weekpm" => 320.0
    "nonweekam" => 220.0
    "nonweekpm" => 420.0
  ]
]
```

Can somebody help me to resolve this ? or please suggest me any mysql query that can do this in single query instead of going through foreach loop. Thank you

Comment: I din't get your whole code, but i think you are trying to check
`if ( notEmpty And notNULL)` . So use `&&` operator instead of `||` operator

Comment: The expected vs the results you are getting look the same to me more or less. I don't see any repeating values

Comment: @apokryfos : Please check the `nonweekpm` value in both arrays you will get to know what i was trying to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to join the asset ids so you're getting gibberish when looping. Do this:

```
$prices = BundlePrice::where('bundle_id',$id)->get()->groupBy("asset_id"); //The group by is done on the collection, not the query: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-groupby
foreach($prices as $bundleprice) {   
    $price = collect($bundleprice)->where("price_id",1)->first();
    $default = collect($bundleprice)->where("price_id",2)->first();
    if (empty($price) && empty($default)) { continue; }
    if (empty($default)) {
        $default = $price;
    }
    $weekam =  !empty($price->weekday_am)?$price->weekday_am:$default->weekday_am;
    $weekpm = !empty($price->weekday_pm)?$price->weekday_pm:$default->weekday_pm;
    $nonweekam = !empty($price->weekend_am)?$price->weekend_am:$default->weekend_am;
    $nonweekpm = !empty($price->weekend_pm)?$price->weekend_pm:$default->weekend_pm;
    $primaryArray[] = ['asset_id' => $default->asset_id,'weekam' => $weekam,'weekpm' => $weekpm,'nonweekam' => $nonweekam,'nonweekpm' => $nonweekpm];        
}
```

Looks a bit cleaner too.